# Navigation bar appear on click on view

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, navigationbar, swift5

[I attach the video of my issue. When i click on anywhere in viewcontroller navigation bar is appear](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gblsjtxgz22lvf/Screen%20Recording%202020-01-25%20at%201.37.37%20PM.mov?dl=0)

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
}
```

The above code added on viewwillappear its working on initially but when I click anywhere on screen navigationbar is appear.

Comment: Are you using `SceneDelegate`?

Comment: This project created in xcode 10

Comment: Can you show me your `AppDelegate`, where you have defined your `NavigationController`?

Comment: let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let navigationController:UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
   let rootViewController:UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NexaRootSideMenuViewController") as! NexaRootSideMenuViewController
    navigationController.viewControllers = [rootViewController]
    navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
                    appdelegate.window?.rootViewController = navigationController

Comment: Try this: `navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)`

Comment: I also try with this code not working.

Comment: Did you write anything regarding navigation except viewDidLoad(), viewWillAppear() or viewDidAppear(). Please check it by mistake written then find it.

Comment: The video shows the actual navigation-bar appearing. But the view-controller appears to have a "navigation-bar" with back button setup. Is this a custom view-controller with a custom navigation setup? On tap making the navigation-bar appear must be declared and defined intended... this is no iOS behaviour. Please take a look at the code embedding/ presenting the view-controller. There must be a  gesture-/ touch- handler showing and hiding the navigation-bar on tap. Tip: if you share code, please update the question, reading code snippets from the comments is hard.

Comment: I update my answer @EelcoKoelewijn please check it. I create custom navigation controller and hide system navigation controller but after few screen transaction navigation bar appear automatically.

Comment: `self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true` This causes the navigation bar to show when you tap the content area of the screen. Please have a look at the documentation of the UINavigationController. It states the following: "When the value of this property is true, the navigation controller toggles the hiding and showing of its navigation bar and toolbar in response to an otherwise unhandled tap in the content area."

Comment: @kishorsoneji `self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true` 
If you write this then it's going to happen.
Is there any specific reason behind adding that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally this solutions work for me

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -200)
```

Comment: This is a solution, but what it does is moving the navigation-bar offscreen. The behaviour of showing the navigation-bar on tap is still happening. I would suggest to resolve the real cause and make a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Try** Below code into `ViewController` you want to hide `NavigationBar`

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    //Below code conflicts with the hidden `NavigationBar` and make it visible on tap so set it false as below
    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = false
}
```

**And ADD** Below code in Other `ViewController` you want to show `Navigationbar` (Not in every other `ViewController` , just in `ViewController` you push or pop from this`ViewController`)

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
```

Comment: No sir, When I tap on screen that time navigation is appear please see video carefully

Answer (score 0):

**Try with global queue**

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
     navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}
```

or simple add this code in `viewDidAppear`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}
```

if this two won't work then check your view tap event may be there is some code added for navigation

Comment: No sir, When I tap on screen that time navigation is appear please see video carefully

Comment: I saw that there may be some event is fired on view tap.
disable user interaction of view:
`self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`.
and try to tap on your screen still navigation is appear on not?

Comment: No any event fire on Tap @NøBi Mac

Comment: Have you disabled user interaction on you screen?

Comment: When you disbale superview user interaction disable automatically child view user interaction is disable.

Comment: Yes i knew that, but check it if interaction of view is disabled at that time this navigation is appearing or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your main UINavigationController storyboard properties in storyboard and uncheck the "Hide bars when vertically compact", "Hide bars on tap". this causes the navigation bar to appear when click on view.

if you are creating UINavigationController programmatically then use following code.

```
UINavigationController().hidesBarsWhenVerticallyCompact = false
UINavigationController().hidesBarsOnTap = false
```

[image]

Comment: change this in your viewWillAppear " navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = false " and i've edited my above answer and try, mainly uncheck all options under "Hide Bars section in storyboard"

Comment: override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = false
}

Comment: Please check my video. View is already appear but issue is after few movement user click on view navigation is appear @Sam'sHell811

Comment: i've seen your video, Did you try above step this will solve your problem i've created same scenario if anyone check Hide bars "On tap" and "When vertically compact" then this issue occur so uncheck it in storyboard or change both properties to false programmatically as i've seen in your above code you've used hidesBarOnTap = true which is creating the problem so make it false.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY TO BELOW**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    navigationItem.title = ""
}
```

Comment: check this solution. @kishor-soneji

Comment: Please check the video @JhonnyTawk Initially navigation bar is hide when I click on window that time navigation is appear.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem too.Storyboard I deleted and recreated the viewController and it was fixed. For this reason I think the problem is related to the viewController not related to the NavigationController. I suggest you delete and recreate the viewController.